# Fill password with Selenium Chrome C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

today the login page was changed https://fastinvest.com/de/investor/login and I am not able to fill in the password with selenium and chrome webdriver.

I usually use XPath, but the form fields will not be filled out. I also tried to execute a javascript but I couldn't make it.

It would be very nice if you could help me to find out how to input the password.

```
            browser = new ChromeDriver("Chrome-Path", options);
            browser.Url = "https://fastinvest.com/de/investor/login";
            browser.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

            IWebElement elem = browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#loginEmail.form-control"));
            elem.SendKeys("test@gmail.com");
            elem.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#loginPassword.form-control")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by name:

```
elem.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");
```

This will work too:

```
elem.FindElement(By.Id("loginPassword")).SendKeys("test@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Hi this does't work, the password form is kind of hidden

Comment: What do you mean? Its not hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a browser control to post username/password to a server. In your case it can be:

```
string url = "https://fastinvest.com/de/auth/login";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "_token","MNpOE4CLgMAelhtwNmG5dhxt1JCUCZsbj9CXnwQT" },
        {"email","aa@bb.com" },
        {"password","12345" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

PS: See the html content of your site and inspect the *FORM* element